# In App Billing Android

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have a product which a user can buy multiple times. Therefore I consume the purchase just after the purchase.
But then the purchase isn't listed in the GetPurchase method from the IInAppBillingService.aidl. Is it a problem on my end?
If a user uninstalls and reinstalls the app I would like to know wether the user bought the in-app product before. Do I need to use a different method of checking instead of using 'consume'? If I don't consume the purchase, it is listed in the GetPurchase method.

Comment: Yea, the GetPurchase method, you know. By the way, if you want to save data, try to read documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html look there to find what fits you the best. If you want to keep data between app installs/reinstalls i'd use sdcard files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if the user is logged in on 2 devices, I still what to know if he has bought it.

Comment: So use an external database like mysql + php.

Comment: Okay, so that is the best solution?

Comment: If you need sync between devices, its the only solution.

Comment: If you use In-app billing, the billing info is stored on your google account. So if it works, getting the billing info from google, when you consume products, it will be the best solution. But it seems not to be working like that.